# Firebase authenticating the user even if the facebook app that provided permissions is removed

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using https://rnfirebase.io/ for react native application. I am successfully able to log in the user using Facebook Login.

My question is, once I have logged in the user using facebook, and then I am deleting the app from my facebook profile that gave permissions to firebase, the firebase is still authenticating me.

So, in this way, I will always be authenticated until I signout? Is this correct? or should I request for fresh Access Tokens ?

Here is the code I am using to check if the user is logged in

```
  _bootStrap = () => {
        let route = Home;
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            saveDataInAsyncStorage('userLoginInfo', user);
            this._navigate(route, result);
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your client app get a valid ID token from Firebase Authentication, it remains valid for one hour after it was issued, even if you do something to disable the user.  The user will be able to use that token to gain access to resources in Firebase until it expires.  At that point, the client SDK will attempt to refresh the token.  If the account is disabled in some way, the refresh will fail, the the previous token will no longer have the access it once had.

So, you will have to wait at least an hour for that user to be rejected by things like Firebase security rules and Firebase Admin token validation.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand you. I am not storing the FB access tokens anywhere. So, by valid ID Token, u mean to say `Uid` ? Can u please explain, how the the client SDK will attempt to refresh the token?  Will it again contact the facebook to check if the app still has the permissions?

Comment: Thankx for the link, but the firebase Admin SDK is authenticating with my custom server setup. My question is, when the client SDK will try to get the FB access tokens again because I have deleted the app that provided permissions to firebase  from my FB profile?

Comment: In one hour, as all tokens issued by Firebase Auth.  You need to expect that.  It doesn't matter which auth provider is being used.